# Reading back into a BST from file

Tags: java, serialization

This is kind of a confusing question so I apologize as I'm not quite sure how to phrase it. Basically what I'm doing is working with sorting binary search trees. Throughout the program, the user adds a record to the tree, which is a node containing `(int studentNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String major, double gpa)`. At the end of the program, the nodes are transposed to a LinkedList with a custom `Node` class I made, and then that list is serialized into a file.

Now, on start up, I want to basically read that file back into another list, display the list, then add it back into the BST so it can be sorted in various ways. My question stands on the point of reading each line (node) in the file and pulling the fields `(int studentNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String major, double gpa)` back into the tree from each "node". This is what I have so far in my read section:

```
public void loadRecord(LinkedList list) {

    File file = new File("records.txt"); 

    try
    {

        LinkedList<Node> list2;
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        list2 = (LinkedList<Node>)input.readObject();
        if (list2.size() > 0){
            list.addAll(list2);
        }//end if
        else {
            System.out.println("No elements");
        }

    }
    //Catch Exceptions
   //display list
}//end loadRecord
```

Once again.. I apologize if this makes no sense at all. And it's very possible I'm going in the completely wrong direction, so I appreciate any feedback. Please let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

First, a
 linked list and a binary search tree are two **different** data structures. You can't make one with another.
Let's say you have a list of numbers you want to store. The data is added to both structures in the same order. The linked list will look something like:

```
|5|-->|3|-->|7|-->|2|-->|6|-->|4|-->|8|-->|1|
```

- "|x|" represents a node with x the data stored in it.
- The arrow represents the reference a node has to its next.
- data is ordered the same way it is entered.

The binary search tree:

```
                         5 
                        / \
                       /   \
                      3     7
                     / \   / \
                    2   4 6   8
                   /            
                  1
```

- For each parent node there is a reference for a left node and a right node. The data in the left child node is smaller than the data in parent node and the data on the right child node is larger on that of the parent.

Therefore, whatever data is being entered it must be 'comparable' in a sense that one value can be larger or smaller than another. So if your data stored is students then one student must be of larger value than another(higher gpa, larger student number, last alphabetically in name, etc.).

Unlike a linked list, the standard API doesn't provide a binary search tree class.So you have implement your own. You need to be familiar with recursion to implement the BST. Make sure you decide how students are compared and implement the tree accordingly. Here is a link that can help :[Binary Search Tree and Tree Traversal](http://www.javabeat.net/binary-search-tree-traversal-java/) .

Next, you need to extract the student info from the record file and store it in the tree. It would help if you stated how the student information is ordered in the `record.txt` file.For now, I will assume that it is ordered such that data of each student is written in one line. I would implement a method in custom node(should called student) class that takes in a line,parses it, and store the data in the student's fields.
Then I would make a while loop that creates a new student, adds the current line to the appropriate method of the student object, and adds the student object into the tree as long as there is a next line in the input stream.

As I said, I will need more information on record file to explain further. Let me know if you need anymore clarifications.